# dropdown (select box) get Name of selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code on [Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/c93MB/)

I have the picture portion of my code working, where it will change picture every time you select a value.

What I want to display is the actual Name " Image 1 " of the value.. so Image 1 etc.

I went through stackoverflow and found some examples, and I tried to implement them but i can't get it to work.

So in short, when you select an a value... it will show picture and in the empty div it will show the name

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#image").change(function() {
     $("#imagePreview").empty();
        $("#imagePreview").append("<img src=\"" + $("#image").val()  + "\" />");
   }).change();
 });

$('#image option:selected').text(); {

   $( "div" ).text( str );
}

<select name="image" id="image" class="inputbox" size="1">
   <option value="imageall.jpg" selected> - All - </option>
   <option value="image1.jpg">image1.jpg</option>
   <option value="image2.jpg">image2.jpg</option>
   <option value="image3.jpg">image3.jpg</option>
</select>

<div id="imagePreview">
   displays image here
</div>

<div></div>
```

EDIT:  Something like this : [EXAMPLE](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Comment: Really got confused about what you are asking..? can you add some bit more details to it..?

Comment: I want to get the NAME of the selected element to APPEAR beside the picture.

SO when picture show up below it will write Image 1 and the name will change with every change in options

why downgrade something you don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#image").change(function () {
        $("#imagePreview").empty();
        $("#imagePreview").append("<img src=\"" + $(this).val() + "\" />");
        $("div:last").text($('option:selected', this).text());
    }).change();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c93MB/1/)

Comment: what does the div:last do?  if you remove last what happens? it seems to duplicate like crazy?

Comment: @op1001 As per the demo you have provided, we have to display the text into the last div right..? that's why I had used the `:last` selector out there.. The better option would be add an id to the displayer div and replace its id with `div:last`..   something like this http://jsfiddle.net/c93MB/6/

Comment: Like this right?  http://jsfiddle.net/c93MB/8/

if you take last out it just repeats and repeats

like this http://jsfiddle.net/c93MB/9/ weird.